# is it possible to have a union of arrays in c

Tags: c

I wish to have a type which can be used as two different array structures - depending on context. They are not to be used interchangeably whilst the program is executing, rather when the program is executed with a particular start-up flag the type will be addressed as one of the array types
(for example):

array1[2][100]
or
array2[200];

I am not interested in how the data is organised (well I am but it is not relevant to what I wish to achieve)

```
union m_arrays
{
   uint16_t array1[2][100];
   uint16_t array2[200];
};
```

or do I have to use a pointer and alloc it at runtime?

```
uint16_t * array;

array = malloc(200 * sizeof(uint16_t));
uint16_t  m_value  =100;

*(array + 199) = m_value;
//equivalent uint16_t  array1[1][99] == *(array + 199);
//equivalent uint16_t  array2[199] == *(array + 199);
```

I haven't tried anything as yet

Comment: I am afraid that you will have a union of two pointers to two arrays. I did not need this kind of hack before, so I cannot formulate a proper answer.

Comment: Unions of arrays are no different from unions of anything else  in 
any way.

Comment: so should the above "work"?

Comment: Yes you can have arrays in unions. It's actually very common. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: I thought that it may lead to some unpredictable behaviour

Comment: No it's fine. Also, C explicitly allows *type-punning* through unions. So you can write to one member and read from another.

Comment: I suppose the follow up from that will be. How would the data in each of the arrays be arranged for each type?

Comment: I understand that but since the way the memory is distributed is not a factor in my usage. The second would work fine. It's just that I would rather have the type on the stack. Whoops sorry I see what you mean. I didn't mean to type 2 asterisks..

Comment: Please note that there never exists a case in C where you should write `*(array + 199)`. Always write `array[199]`.

Comment: OT: "equivalent uint16_t  array1[1][99] == *(array + 199);" oh no... it's not

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think all versions of C allow type-punning through unions. And even if it is defined, I'd avoid it whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

A union as itself contains *either* of its members. That is, only one member can be "bound" at a time (this is just an abstraction, since C has no notion about which member is "active").

In general, the effective size of that union will be the higher size on bytes of its members.

Let me give an example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union m_arrays
{
   int array1[2][100];
   int array2[400];
} a;

int main()
{
    printf("%zu", sizeof(a));

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, this would print 1600 (assuming `int` is 4 bytes long, but at the end it will depend on the architecture) and is the highest size in bytes. So, **YES**, you can have a union of arrays in C

Comment: `sizeof` returns a `size_t`. To print a `size_t` use `%zu`

Comment: I don't think that C has a notion of an active member of a union. Each of member can be accessed at any time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this does work, and it's actually precisely because of how arrays are different from pointers. I'm sure you've heard that arrays in C are really just pointers, but the truth is that there are some important differences.

First, an array always points to somewhere on the stack. You can't use `malloc` to make an array because `malloc` returns a heap address. A pointer can point anywhere, you can even set it to an arbitrary integer if you want (though there's no guaruntee you can access that memory that it points to).

Second, because arrays are fixed length, the compiler can and does allocate them for you when you declare them. Importantly, this comes with the guaruntee that the whole array is in one continuous memory block. So if you declare `int arr[2][100]`, you'll have 200 int slots allocated in a row on the stack. That means you can treat any multimensional array as a single-dimensional array if you want to, e.g. instead of `arr[y][x]` you could do `arr[0][y*100+x]`. You could also do something like `int* arr2 = arr` and then treat `arr2` as a regular array even though `arr` is technically an `int**` (you'll get a warning for doing either of these things, my point is that you *can* do them because of how arrays are made).

The third, and probably most important difference, is a consequence of the second. When you have an array in a struct or union, the struct/union isn't just holding a pointer to the first element. It holds the entire array. This is often used for copying arrays or returning them from functions. What this means for you is that what you want to do works despite what someone who's heard that arrays are pointers might initially think. If arrays were just an address and they were initialized by allocating at that address, there would be two different arrays initialized at two different places, and having the pointers to them in a union would mean one gets overwritten and now you have an array somewhere that you can't access.

So when this all comes together, your union of arrays basically has one array with two different ways of accessing the data (which is what you want if I'm not mistaken). A little example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    union {
        int arr1[4];
        int arr2[2][2];
    } u;
    u.arr1[0] = 1;
    u.arr1[1] = 2;
    u.arr1[2] = 3;
    u.arr1[3] = 4;
    printf("%d %d\n%d %d\n", u.arr2[0][0], u.arr2[0][1], u.arr2[1][0], u.arr2[1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
```

We can also quickly walk through why this wouldn't work with pure pointers. Let's say we instead had a union like this:

```
union {
    int* arr1;
    int** arr2;
} u;
```

Then we might initialize with `u.arr1 = (int*) malloc(4 * sizeof (int));`. Then we could use `arr1` like a normal array. But what happens when we try to use `arr2`? Well, `arr2[y][x]` is of course syntactic sugar for `*(*(arr2+y)+x))`. Once it's dereferenced that first time, we now have an int, since the address points to an int. So when we add x to that int and try to dereference again, we're trying to dereference an int. C will try to do it, and if you're very unlucky it will succeed; I say unlucky because then you'll be messing with arbitrary memory. What's more likely is a segfault because whatever int is there is most likely not an address your program has access to.

Comment: Re “First, an array always points to somewhere on the stack”: Arrays may exist on the memory used for static objects or may be allocated with `malloc`; they do not just exist in (not “point to”) the stack. (With `malloc`, you cannot have a name for the array, but you can have a pointer to the array, although often just a pointer to an element is used, and the array is in the allocated memory.)

Comment: Re “you can even set it to an arbitrary integer if you want”: This may work in some C implementations but is not guaranteed by the standard, and this suggestion should not be made to people learning C without appropriate cautions.

Comment: Re “That means you can treat any multimensional array as a single-dimensional array if you want to, e.g. instead of `arr[y][x]` you could do `arr[0][y*100+x]`.”: The behavior of this is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Re “You could also do something like `int* arr2 = arr` and then treat `arr2` as a regular array even though `arr` is technically an `int**`”: No, if `arr` is an `int **`, then using `arr2` as a regular array, an `int []`, will attempt to access the pointers in `arr` as if they were `int`. You may have mean “even though `arr` is technically an `int [][]`”, which is different from an `int **`, but the behavior of that is also not defined by the C standard.

Comment: 1) You can't assign to an array, so you can only use what it gets set to when it's initialized, which is a stack address    

2) How you would like the word "heap" to be used does not change the fact that people use it to mean dynamically allocated memory    

3) I noted that you shouldn't set a pointer to an integer. My point is that as opposed to an array, you can    

4) `a[i]` gets converted to `*(a+i)`, you can figure the rest out yourself to see that it is guarunteed to work    

5) "technically an `int**`" was poor wording, but the meaning should have been clear

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Indeed, gcc will sometimes process code that would attempt to access element `[0][3]` of an `int[5][3]` in ways that will arbitrarily corrupt memory.